# Как правильно сделать БД для блога с поиском по тэгам?

Tags: sql, база-данных, веб-сервер

Добрый день.
Я сейчас в учебных целях пробую создать с нуля блог - просто чтобы понять внутреннюю механику подобных веб-приложений.
Пытаюсь распланировать БД, но поскольку в этой области я нуб, возникают вопросы.

Вот один из них:

Я хочу сделать, чтобы посты можно было помечать текстовыми тэгами, по которым потом осуществлять фильтрацию. Для каждого поста может быть список из нескольких тэгов, сколько именно - неизвестно.
Перечень тэгов заранее не определён, должна быть возможность создавать запись с тэгами, которые ранее ещё не использовались.
Но при этом хочется иметь возможность быстро получить список всех тэгов, существующих в блоге на данный момент.

Как это правильнее сделать в БД?

Мне приходит в голову только одно: сделать одно поле, куда вводить список тэгов через некий разделитель.

Но у меня сомнения: насколько такой подход эффективен в плане скорости поиска?

И как из него получить список всех существующих тегов? Можно ли это сразу сделать каким-то хитрым запросом? Или нужно получать это поле для всех записей, передавать его в серверный скрипт, который будет уже разрезать строки по разделителю, и составлять список, отлавливая повторы? И насколько это будет эффективно?

Понятно, что в рамках моего учебного примера это всё будет работать достаточно быстро, поскольку количество записей мизерное.
Но как подобную задачу правильно решать на реальных блоговых сервисах с большим количеством пользователей?

Comment: создавайте отдельную таблицу для связи поста и его тегов, например можно было бы  сделать так: Таблица справочник **Tags**, таблица постов **Posts**,  для соединения создади таблицу **PosTags** со следующими колонками **PostId**, **TagId** на основании которой можно будет получить все теги поста или все посты с определенным тегом/набором тегов

Comment: @Bald, спасибо за ответ. Ваш вариант выглядит гораздо более адекватным, чем мой :)) Если никто не предложит более интересных вариантов, то я так и сделаю. Случайно не знаете - на реальных блогах так и делают тэги?